# javascript disabling form submission until functions are true

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two functions, the first checks to see if the terms and conditions checkbox has been checked and if at least one checkbox from a span class of events which each has a checkbox next to it has been checked, if both function conditions have been met then the disabled submission button should be enabled but it doesn't seem to work.

Code for the start of the form

```
<form id="bookingForm" name"form1" action="#" method="get">
```

code for the terms and conditions

```
<div id="ChangeTextScript">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions</div> 
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onclick= "goFurther(); changetext(this,'ChangeTextScript');">
```

Submit button code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make booking" id="sub1" disabled=disable />
```

Javascript code

The 2 functions

```
function goFurther(){
if (document.getElementById("termsChkbx").checked == true) {
    return true;
}   else {
return false;
  }}

function checkCheckboxes() {
if (document.querySelector('input[name="event\\[\\]"]:checked') >= 1 ) {
    return true;
}   else {
    return false;
}}
```

The code that checks to see if both functions has been met then it should enable the button

```
if(checkCheckboxes() && goFurther()) {
    return true;
     document.getElementById("sub1").disabled = false;
}   else {
document.getElementById("sub1").disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: You need to call that code in the `onchange` handler of all the input elements that you want to check.

Comment: Also, you might want to add an actual question to your post. I would further suggest that you look at something like `knockout.js` as it makes enabling or disabling controls based on functions like this very trivial.

Comment: but knockout.js is not trivial in itself :)

Comment: Your `checkCheckboxes` function isn't working correctly, the `if` statement compares an object with a number, you should rather do `if( document.querySelector(..) !== null ){ ... }`. Also, `querySelector` will only ever return 1 element, use `querySelectorAll` if you are searching for more than 1.

Comment: would you mind showing how i could change it for it to work? I am quite new the javascript

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked this over two months ago, but in the case that you're still looking for an answer, the best way to accomplish this is via an `onchange` event handler attached to the form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1"> option 1
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2"> option 2
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3"> option 3
    </span>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tnc"> I agree to the Terms & Conditions.
    </div>
    <button id="disabled" disabled>submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("myform").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("disabled").disabled = 
        !(document.getElementById("tnc").checked && 
            (   document.getElementById("cb1").checked ||
                document.getElementById("cb2").checked ||
                document.getElementById("cb3").checked    ) );
}
```

The basic idea is to set the `disabled` property of the `#disabled` button to the negation of the following condition:

```
document.getElementById("tnc").checked && conditionB
```

where `conditionB` is equal to

```
document.getElementById("cb1").checked || document.getElementById("cb2").checked || document.getElementById("cb3").checked;
```

This only returns `true` when `#tnc` is checked, along with one of the input boxes in the span (`#cb1`, `#cb2`, or `#cb3`). That means the `.disabled` property is equal to `!true` (aka `false`) when the aforementioned requirements are met.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53C4n/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If this is the only thing you need to do, you could encapsulate the code that checks the functions in a while loop. Also, I see that you return true before the button is enabled. This stops execution of the function while returning true. You would like to place this return statement after the button is enabled.

Comment: You most definitely do not want to do this. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/2yjyK/) is essentially what you're suggesting. (Notice how it never loads.) That's a `while (true) {}` loop.